# Need a substitute for "where" clause in documentDB to bulk update collection attributes

Tags: mongodb, where-clause, aws-documentdb

I am working in an hybrid environment where we have some of our databases running in MongoDB servers and some have been migrated to AWS DocumentDB.

in these databases there are a number of fields that contain invalid data from earlier iterations of our development process. We need to delete a number of fields where multiple "updated" records exist. This was easy enough in our development environment where we were abler to use the following code

```
b.getCollection(<collectionname>).updateMany({ $where: "this.updated.length > 1" }, {$set:{"updated":[{"username":"SYSTEM","userId":"SYSTEM","cannonicalUserId":"SYSTEM","time":"2021-09-13T16:36:10.725+00:00"}]}});
```

But I am unable to execute this code in my DocumentDB instances because the "where:" is not a compatible keyword.

I have looked at a number of alternatives, but I am concerned that I may not be properly applying the conditional set logic, and will overwrite data I should be preserving.

If anyone can point me at the correct, DocumentDB compatible operation, I would be greatly obliged. Examples are greatly appreciated.

*Engine version is docdb 4.0.0*

Thanks!

Comment: what is the datatype of the field "this.updated"?   Is this an array?

Comment: yes its an array of objects. 
we need to delete the items of this array if there are more than one entry. 
we are trying to implement code to make this field into a singleton record indicating the latest update information, but this breaks when there are multiple updated records.  
we want to clean up the data that breaks the rule to continue testing

Comment: to make it a singleton simply change from an array to an object.

Comment: what I want to do is:  
WHERE there is multiple updated records, 
replace with the single record indicated in my OP. 

converting all the arrays into some flat aggregated text data is not useful 
Converting the data type is not the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aggregation that may help...

Example:

**Insert Some Data**

```
db.collection.insert({this: {updated: [1, 2, 3]}})
db.collection.insert({this: {updated: [4]}})
db.collection.insert({this: {updated: [6, 7]}})
db.collection.insert({this: {updated: [8]}})
```

**Show Data**

```
db.collection.find()
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5af9cc4f9e4b168781"),
    this: { updated: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5af9cc4f9e4b168782"),
    this: { updated: [ 4 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5af9cc4f9e4b168783"),
    this: { updated: [ 6, 7 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5bf9cc4f9e4b168784"),
    this: { updated: [ 8 ] }
  }
]
```

**Aggregation**

Now run a query for just those having more than 1 element in field this.updated...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     { $addFields: { "size": { $size: "$this.updated"} } },
     { $match: {"size": {$gt: 1} } },
     { $project: { "size": 0 } }
])
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5af9cc4f9e4b168781"),
    this: { updated: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61b92f5af9cc4f9e4b168783"),
    this: { updated: [ 6, 7 ] }
  }
]
```